# PUT-parameters in django-rest-framework + OAuth 1.0a

Tags: python, django, rest, oauth, django-rest-framework

pip freeze

```
Django==1.6.2
Markdown==2.3.1
South==0.8.4
argparse==1.2.1
django-filter==0.7
django-guardian==1.1.1
django-oauth-plus==2.2.3
django-registration==1.0
djangorestframework==2.3.11
httplib2==0.8
ipdb==0.8
ipython==2.0.0
oauth2==1.5.211
psycopg2==2.5.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Request:

```
PUT /api/v1/place/14/ BODY: name=NEW3&latitude=55.74659&longitude=37.626484
```

Response:

```
{"detail": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: PUT&http%3A%2F%2Fyavezu.com%3A8005%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fplace%2F14%2F&oauth_consumer_key%3Daa68ec89fc944c60880f59e18dc6e982%26oauth_nonce%3D-4587244018477714645%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1398769361%26oauth_token%3D03cd9df066244aa2884a5508ff0d9fff%26oauth_version%3D1.0"}
```

As you can see PUT-parameters are not included in base string.

I digged a code a little and found two reasons for it.

1. PUT-parameters are not supported in oauth_provider

see line:

```
if request.method == "POST" and request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE') == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
```

oauth_provider.utils

```
def get_oauth_request(request):
    """ Converts a Django request object into an `oauth2.Request` object. """
    # Django converts Authorization header in HTTP_AUTHORIZATION
    # Warning: it doesn't happen in tests but it's useful, do not remove!
    auth_header = {}
    if 'Authorization' in request.META:
        auth_header = {'Authorization': request.META['Authorization']}
    elif 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
        auth_header =  {'Authorization': request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']}


    # include POST parameters if content type is
    # 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and request
    # see: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#section-3.4.1.3.1
    parameters = {}

    if request.method == "POST" and request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE') == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
        parameters = dict((k, v.encode('utf-8')) for (k, v) in request.POST.iteritems())

    absolute_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(request.path)

    if "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" in request.META:
        scheme = request.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]
        absolute_uri = urlunparse((scheme, ) + urlparse(absolute_uri)[1:])

    return oauth.Request.from_request(request.method,
        absolute_uri,
        headers=auth_header,
        parameters=parameters,
        query_string=request.META.get('QUERY_STRING', '')
    )
```

1. PUT-parameters are not supported in class `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest` and `django.http.request.HttpRequest`:

   def _load_post_and_files(self):
       """Populate self._post and self._files if the content-type is a form type"""
       if self.method != 'POST':
           self._post, self._files = QueryDict('', encoding=self._encoding), MultiValueDict()
           return
   ...

I wounder how it is possible for Django REST Framework to provide RESTful API over Django without support for PUT-parameters? What am I doing wrong?
POST-requests work just fine.

I also asked this question on Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/django-rest-framework/679fOg0QpzI

Comment: It looks like this fix for django-oauth-plus should help:

    if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', None) == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
        if request.method == 'POST':
            parameters = request.POST
        else:
            parameters = getattr(request, 'DATA', {})
        parameters = dict((k, v.encode('utf-8')) for (k, v) in parameters.iteritems())

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer on the [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/django-rest-framework/679fOg0QpzI)...

I'd suggest either:

1. Instead putting the authentication information in the Authorization header, which django-oauth-plus also correctly supports.
2. Submitting a pull request to django-oauth-plus adding support for including x-www-form-urlencoded oauth parameters in non-POST message bodies.

Either way the issue isn't that REST framework doesn't support parsing data in PUT requests - it does, and request.DATA will still be populated as normal.